# Obtaining checkbox values for n number of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to implement bulk action functionality for data displayed from an sql database on a webpage. I've echoed out the data into html format, and I'm trying to add a checkbox feature where the user can select any number of rows and then perform a bulk action with them by choosing a value from a dropdown, e.g. delete- and all selected values will be deleted from the database. I'm stumbling a bit though with obtaining the selected checkbox values once the perform action button is submitted. I've put my attempt at the code below- I'm getting invalid foreach argument provided error message. I'm fairly certain it has something to do with my input loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
//establish connection to database:
        require 'DB.php';

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names", $conn);
        echo "<tr>";

        //echo results while rows of data remain... 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo '<tr><td>' . $row['NAME'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="checked[' . $row['NAME'] . ']" value="' . $row['NAME'] .'"></td>';
        }

        ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?

if (isset($_POST['perform_action'])) {

    //check checkbox values
    foreach ($_POST['checked'] as $check) {
        echo $check;
    }

    //do something with the values
    if ($_POST['bulk_action'] == 'delete') {
        echo "you chose to delete";
    }
```

Comment: Try `name="checked[' . $row['NAME'] . '][]"` notice the extra `[]`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['perform_action'])) {
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names", $conn);
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
       if (isset($_POST["checked".$row['NAME']])){
           //hear you can do anything to your checked checkbox

          }

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before working on the posted data, you need to make sure that it is exist.

In your code, if you submit the form without choose any of the check boxes, you will face the **invalid foreach argument provided** message, so you need to check if field `$_POST['checked']` is exist then run the loop.

So change the

```
foreach ($_POST['checked'] as $check) {
    echo $check;
}
```

To

```
    //check checkbox values
  if(isset($_POST['checked'])){
    foreach ($_POST['checked'] as $check) {
        echo $check;
    }
  }
```